# Angular 6 iframe binding

Tags: html, angular, typescript, iframe

There is a variable that stores iframe code.
I want to bind this in a div, but nothing work.

html:

```
<div class="top-image" [innerHTML]="yt"></div>
```

ts:

```
yt = '<iframe class="w-100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KS76EghdCcY?rel=0&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably might get a warning saying that it's unsafe HTML. That's why Angular is not rendering it inside the `div`.

You'll have to `DomSanitize` it:

```
<div class="top-image" [innerHTML]="yt | safe: 'html'"></div>
```

Here's the pipe [courtesy Swarna Kishore](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b).

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default:
        throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a **[Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dom-sanitization-eg?file=src/app/safe.pipe.ts)**.

Comment: Confirmed this is still working in angular 12.2.