# ngIf and click not working for dynamic html in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

ngIf and click not working for dynamic html.

when load html using innerHtml then ngIf and click event not loading.

```
export class FillInBlanksComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {    

     question = '';
     editable = true;
     ngOnInit() {    

         question = '<span *ngIf="editable" name="answers['+incr+']" contenteditable="true" (click)="onclick()"> </span>';
     }
     onClick(){
         alert("clicked!!!!");
     }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you're calling is `(click)="onclick()"` but you've defined `onClick()`.

Another thing is, you might want to DOM Sanitize the string else you'll get a warning. Please check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52382743/2622292) out on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

check you have done spelling mistake use (click)="onClick()"

you are using small c in your function call