# Convert url to secure url link can be recognized by iframe

Tags: javascript, angular

How to convert url to secure url link that can be recognized by iframe in angular

```
  <iframe src="{{url}}"></iframe>
```

Comment: Check this answer (to possible duplicate question) https://stackoverflow.com/a/38037914/2050306

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 iframe binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382608/angular-6-iframe-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this below

**secure-pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'secure' })
export class SecurePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   declarations : [
     ...
     SecurePipe
   ],
})
```

**In Html**

```
<iframe [src]="url | secure"></iframe>
```