# Link manipulation (DOM-based) Security Issues - Angular 7 Application

Tags: angular, security

I ran security tests for my angular application using burp tool, one of the issues that has been raised by the same is:
Link manipulation (DOM-based)

The detailed explanation for the issue is provided in the below URL:

https://portswigger.net/kb/issues/00501000_link-manipulation-dom-based

As per my understanding, the links that I have used in the HTML file is creating this issue, links such as:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.min.css">
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382608/angular-6-iframe-binding/52382743#52382743)

Comment: What are you asking? What have you tried to resolve the problem and show example source code of what you're doing.

Comment: @SiddAjmera The solution for that question won't hep me resolve the issue here.